# Embedding Images In Programs?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# WinForm application that has a few images on it.
I can specify the image location, but what I want is for the image to go with the file after it publishes.  It still displays the one specified in the image location, so if a user doesn't have access to that location, he/she won't be able to see the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magic word you're looking for is "resources". Have a look at the MSDN article on [Adding and Editing Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Thomas link, you can try the following:

Add an Image into your form. Change in the properties "Build Action" field. The `Build Action` property indicates what Visual Studio does with a file when a build is executed. Build Action can have one of several values:

- **None** - The file is not included in the project output group and is not compiled in the build process. An example is a text file that contains documentation, such as a Readme file.
- **Compile** - The file is compiled into the build output. This setting is used for code files.
- **Content** - The file is not compiled, but is included in the Content output group. For example, this setting is the default value for an .htm or other kind of Web file.
- **Embedded Resource** - This file is embedded in the main project build output as a DLL or executable. It is typically used for resource files.